# compare 2 histograms with Chi-Square

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, histogram, comparator

i want to compare 2 Histograms, which have 2 dimensions.
For this i want to use the **Chi-Square**-Metric.
My comparator looks like this function:

```cpp
double Histogram::compareHistogram(Histogram *hist){
    double result=0;
    double a=0;
    double b=0;
    for (int y=0 ; y < bins_1 ; y++) {
         for (int x=0 ; x < bins_2 ; x++) {
             a=getHistogramValue(x,y)-hist->getHistogramValue(x,y);
             b=getHistogramValue(x,y)+hist->getHistogramValue(x,y);
             if(fabs(b)>0.0){
               result+=a*a/b;
             }
         }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've compared the result with the result of OpenCv's cv::`compareHist()` function and it is different. I don't know why.

Before i compared the histograms, i norm the histograms with the MINMAX-Norm. 
I compared my normed histogram with the normed histogram  of openCV and they are equal. 
So I think, the problem is in my compareHist function.
But where?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant section of source code from OpenCV is as follows:

```cpp
if( method == CV_COMP_CHISQR )
{
    for( j = 0; j < len; j++ )
    {
        double a = h1[j] - h2[j];
        double b = h1[j];
        if( fabs(b) > DBL_EPSILON )
            result += a*a/b;
    }
}
```

So you can see that the difference in your code is this line

```cpp
b=getHistogramValue(x,y)+hist->getHistogramValue(x,y);
```

which should be

```cpp
b=getHistogramValue(x,y);
```

Comment: oh yeah...you're right. I've showed in an old revision of this code (https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp?rev=4885) thank you